Flooring repair for roll vinyl
Tore tile up in my kitchen with cement board underlayment over plywood subfloor. Can I lay 3/8 plywood over cement board for smooth surface instead of removing all glue & rough spots to lay roll vinyl?

Rolled vinyl is usually quite thin.  Any defects in the smoothness of the flooring will damage the vinyl in no time.  The seams in the plywood will need to be perfectly level with each other, which usually means the sub floor needs to be flat also.

Is the concern floor thickness, to meet an adjacent floor?

Yes... but.

if you lay plywood on it does the glue push it up in spots?
does the plywood help match up with the flooring height in other areas?
does cost of plywood and installing it really worth not scraping off some glue?

Really the main concern is height, so if height matches based on install plywood then do it.   But you might have to fix some of the bigger chunks first.
